# Why not updating my data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Error updating Group. Must declare the scalar variable "@SubnameWHERE"... why this error is showing .....

```
protected void cmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string updateSQL;
        updateSQL = "UPDATE tblnewgroup SET ";
        updateSQL += "Groupname=@Groupname, ";
        updateSQL += "Slno=@Slno, Subname=@Subname";
        updateSQL += "WHERE Groupno=@Groupno_original";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, con);


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Groupname", txtgname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Slno", txtsl.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subname", txtsn.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Groupno_original", lstAuthor.SelectedItem.Value);

    int updated = 0;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        updated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblResults.Text = updated.ToString() + " record updated.";
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lblResults.Text = "Error updating Group. ";
        lblResults.Text += err.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    if (updated > 0)
    {
        FillAuthorList();
    }

}
```

Comment: You may need to add a Space at the end of the line "Slno=@Slno, Subname=@Subname"

Comment: Did you try reading the error, understanding the problem, inspecting the `updateSQL` value, executing the query in there in SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space after your `Subname=@Subname`

Change your

```
updateSQL += "Slno=@Slno, Subname=@Subname";
```

to

```
updateSQL += "Slno=@Slno, Subname=@Subname ";
```

As a better visualization, you can use it like;

```
string updateSQL = @"UPDATE tblnewgroup
                     SET Groupname=@Groupname, Slno=@Slno, Subname=@Subname
                     WHERE Groupno=@Groupno_original";
```

Also you should use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block for dispose your `SqlConnection` like;

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  con.Open();
  updated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Soner has stated - your sql is invalid -

```
updateSQL += "Slno=@Slno, Subname=@Subname";
updateSQL += "WHERE Groupno=@Groupno_original";
```

These two lines will end up as ...`@SubnameWHERE Groupno=`....

Thats your problem!

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** You have combined both parameter `@Subname` and `WHERE` clause.
**Solution :** You need to provide `space` between parameter `@Subname` and `WHERE` clause

Replace This

```
updateSQL += "Slno=@Slno, Subname=@Subname";
```

With This:

```
updateSQL += "Slno=@Slno, Subname=@Subname ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change

```
updateSQL += "WHERE Groupno=@Groupno_original";
```

to

```
updateSQL += " WHERE Groupno=@Groupno_original";
```

Tip: While constructing such sql commands always put a space at the beginning of each string part.

Comment: Thanks Sudhakar Tillapudi, I think you have edited bold character in the code in the answer.